# is pub.dev support snapshot pakage

Tags: flutter, dart

Now I am using this command to upload my public dart lib to pub.dev:

```
flutter pub publish --server=https://pub.dartlang.org
```

the upload was successfully. But when I upload again, it tell me that the package already exists. And now I want to update the package, must I change the version num? does it have a snapshot repo like java, the snapshot version could overwrite by the same version of jar file, or daily build repo? I have searching from google but seems no one talk about it. Sometimes I just do some small improvments, it is not nessasary to upgrade the version. I tried to import the package in local way like this:

```
 wheel:
    path: ../wheel
```

but it will failed in the remote github actions ci process. So I have to upload it to the remote server so I could load the public lib in anywhere. Is other way to hold my daily build lib and when it become stable I could upload to pub.dev.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way may work as expect, just add dependencies in pubspec.yml like this:

```
   wheel:
      git:
         url: https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/wheel.git
         ref: main
```